# Showing multiple images in Android Canvas for Android Game

Tags: android, canvas, sprite

I have three different images and i want to write a code which will randomly select any of these images and display it at the top of the screen.
Then this image will move downwards and once it reaches the bottom of the screen the image will disappear from the screen.

Now this logic should be continued in the loop where these images will keep on appearing at the top and move towards the bottom of the screen.

I am unable to figure out a way for this. I am trying this on the Canvas.

Basically these three images are kind of Weapons (one is arrow, another is bomb and third one is missile). I want a continuous loop where these images will keep on occurring at the top of the screen and moves downwards and disappear once they reach the bottom.

Can anyone please help me with this?